# summernote plugin add more font family etc"Microsoft YaHei"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, editor, summernote

I am using plugin [summernote](https://github.com/summernote/summernote),I want to add more font-family,etc 'Microsoft YaHei'.how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From your summernote font folder if you do not have it add the font library

```
   fontNames: [
        'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New',
        'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande',
        'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana', 'Microsoft YaHei'
      ],
```